# Route outgoing traffic through whonix gateway/tails, allow incoming VPN traffic (me->my VPN server-> Tor)

Tags: linux, vpn, tor

Basically I want to do VPN -> Tor, but with all outgoing traffic from the VPN server going through Tor, and the Virtual Machines only on the VPN server, not on my PC. So I will have a VPN which will send all outgoing traffic through a Tor gateway OS running as a VM (whonix preferably).

This article, [Using Tor and a VPN | Pros and Cons](https://thetinhat.com/tutorials/darknets/tor-vpn-using-both.html), says how you can obviously accomplish this by running a VM on your PC, but I want to keep the VM's on the VPN server.

> If you do insist on routing Tor through your VPN, then the setup is
>   fairly easy. Simply connect to the VPN and then open Whonix.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible:

1. Create and configure a VPN server. OpenVPN is a nice choice.
2. Install and configure OpenVPN client on Whonix gateway.

   You can use the private IP of the server to start the connection. By default, the default connection on Whonix gateway is a NAT-ed interface, so it will reach your server using the internal IP.
3. Run Whonix gateway, change Tor settings to connect using the interface `tun0` or `tap0`, depending on your setup.

   This is the important step. Doing this you will force Tor to route all traffic to the VPN interface, not your public interface.
4. You don't have to change anything on Whonix workstation. It will work as before.